# How to deserialize simple type with json.net?

Tags: json, json.net

Json.net is handy to deserialize object, but I don't know how to use it to deserialize some simple type, such as string, int.

Not sure if I did it right, please help, thank you!

**WCF return string looks like**

```
{"PingResult":100}
```

**If call**

```
int result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(jsonString);
```

**Unity throw**

```
JsonReaderException: Error reading integer. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsInt32Internal ()
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsInt32 ()
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not deserializing an integer, but an object containing an integer property. You need to provide such a class for the deserialization to work, for example:

```
class Ping
{
    public int PingResult {get; set;}
}
```

and then call

```
Ping ping = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ping>(jsonString);
int result = ping.PingResult;
```

Another approach would be to use the [JObject api](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm):

```
string json="{\"PingResult\":100}"; 
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json); 
JToken jToken = jo["PingResult"];
int result = (int)jToken;
```

Comment: Oops, I thought it might can handle this since create new class for each ain't a awesome idea especially if we have lots of method to call :p Still, it's very handy to call JObject API to do so. Thank You dude :] Codes here incase someone need it. `string json="{\"PingResult\":100}";
  JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
  JToken result = jo["PingResult"];`

Comment: I'm glad I've helped, added your example to my answer so that it's more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Deserializing a simple type stored as a string (the title of this question) can be done like this:

```
    private static T ParseStringToTypedValue<T>(string value)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            return JToken.Parse($"\"{value}\"")
                         .Value<T>();
        }

        return JToken.Parse(value)
                     .Value<T>();
    }
```

This should handle all the basic types, floats, ints, strings etc..